# Testing to see if a scheduled task exist in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, scheduled-tasks

I can't figure out why the below code won't work:

```
Function createFirefoxTask() {
   $schedule = new-object -com Schedule.Service 
   $schedule.connect() 
   $tasks = $schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)

   foreach ($task in ($tasks | select Name)) {
      echo "TASK: $task.name"
      if($task.equals("FirefoxMaint")) {
         write-output "$task already exists"
         break
      }
   }
} 
createFirefoxTask
```

The output I get is this:

```
FirefoxMaint                                                                          

TASK: @{Name=FirefoxMaint}.name
TASK: @{Name=Task1}.name
TASK: @{Name=Task2}.name
TASK: @{Name=Task3}.name
TASK: @{Name=Task4}.name
TASK: @{Name=Task5}.name
```

If I echo `$task.name` from the shell without going through the script, it properly displays the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used in a double-quoted string, variable evaluation will stop at punctuation. You can use `$()` to denote a subexpression within a string, like this:

```
"TASK: $($task.name)"
```

PowerShell will then evaluate the expression inside the parentheses and expand the string with the outcome

Comment: Thanks!  That cleared up the one issue I was having.  How come my test is failing?  That job does exist

Comment: @actually the test doesn't fail.. the output is just ugly

Comment: I've come to like the -f operator for string handling, with that you can do: ('TASK: {0}' -f $task.name)

Comment: @Jakob `-f` would indeed be a great alternative here. Post an answer ;-)

Answer (score 43):

In order to prevent errors with Get-ScheduledTask in case the task doesn't exist - you might want to consider doing :

```
$taskName = "FireFoxMaint"
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName }

if($taskExists) {
   # Do whatever 
} else {
   # Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Try this one:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task Name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -OutVariable task

if (!$task) {
    # task does not exist, otherwise $task contains the task object
}
```

Comment: -OutVariable did not work for me. But just returning the variable did.
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName  ...

Answer (score 4):

If you are using v3.0, then you can do this using Get-ScheduledTask.  Forexample,

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "FirefoxMaint" -TaskPath \
```

Then, just need to check the value of $task.

Comment: But if I'm running v3.0, it won't do me any good if the clients whose machine I'll run this on are v1.0 right?

Comment: In 4.0 it appears that this causes an error when the task does not exist.

Comment: @RickRainey is partially correct, the ScheduledTask module uses CIM classes that was only introduced in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 http://stackoverflow.com/a/22644879/740575

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to test to see if a scheduled task exists in PowerShell:

```
if(Get-ScheduledTask FirefoxMaint -ErrorAction Ignore) { #found } else { #not found}
```

Comment: You should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand.

Comment: It's working. Also you can use variable to store the task - $task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -ErrorAction Ignore. It works on PowerShell version 5 o the Windows 10. If not use the ErrorAction it will works also but will print an error to the console.