# How to install ScheduledTasks module on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to install [this module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816.aspx) that ships with PS v3.0++ on OS different then Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012?

I am aware of all PS alternatives but none is so complete as mentioned module (PowerShell Pack's TaskScheduler, ScheduledJobs, schtasks etc..)

It defies logic that such important module can't be installed on older systems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are out of luck. See [the explanation here](http://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/transferring-modules-from-windows-8-or-8-1-to-windows-7/). I'll post a part for completeness:

> The long answer is that you can’t because, for the most part, those
>   modules are based on CIM (WMI) classes that were introduced in Windows
>   8 or 8.1. A lot of the system management functionality you see in
>   modern Windows is based on CIM classes that then use the CDXML
>   approach to create PowerShell modules.
>   Installing the new CIM classes on Windows 7 is not possible – so you can’t get the modules on which they are based.

Answer (score 2):

check out this guys simple batch file it works on windows 7 without powershell and saves all as xml and imports back as xml

If you are exporting and importing to Windows 7 pc's only
replace the line which has

```
del tasks\#Microsoft*.xml
```

with

```
rem del tasks\#Microsoft*.xml
```

[Scheduled tasks export all](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1474-export-and-import-all-scheduled-tasks-in-windows-server-2008-windows-7)

Here is the code in case the link goes down

```
    rem @echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set runasUsername=domain\administrator  
set runasPassword=password



if %1. == export. call :export
if %1. == import. call :import
exit /b 0


:export
md tasks 2>nul

schtasks /query /fo csv | findstr /V /c:"TaskName" > tnlist.txt

for /F "delims=," %%T in (tnlist.txt) do (
  set tn=%%T
  set fn=!tn:\=#!
  echo  !tn!
  schtasks /query /xml /TN !tn! > tasks\!fn!.xml
)

rem Windows 2008 tasks which should not be imported.
del tasks\#Microsoft*.xml
exit /b 0



:import
for %%f in (tasks\*.xml) do (
    call :importfile "%%f"
)
exit /b 0


:importfile
    set filename=%1

    rem replace out the # symbol and .xml to derived the task name
    set taskname=%filename:#=%
    set taskname=%taskname:tasks\=%
    set taskname=%taskname:.xml=%

    schtasks /create /ru %runasUsername% /rp %runasPassword% /tn %taskname% /xml %filename%
    echo.
    echo.
```