# PowerShell / task scheduler / task exist check

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

Before deleting a task in the task scheduler with schtasks command, how can I check that a target task already exists or not with PowerShell?

My question is deferent of yours, and sodawillow solved my problem! thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing to see if a scheduled task exist in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703768/testing-to-see-if-a-scheduled-task-exist-in-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it is in this list:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Select -ExpandProperty TaskName
```