# powershell get name from array of objects

Tags: windows, powershell, server, windows-task-scheduler

I need to get all names of all schedules tasks which i do like this:

```
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select TaskName,LastRunTime,LastTaskResult
```

Output looks something like this:

```
TaskName                                                LastRunTime                                                                                     LastTaskResult
--------                                                -----------                                                                                     --------------
GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore                             31. 5. 2021 0:29:29                                                                                          0
```

Which is alright, but i wanna take only task names and print each one new line.

I tried this:

```
foreach($task in $tasks){
    Write-Host "$task.TaskName"
}
```

But output is this:

```
@{TaskName=Adobe Acrobat Update Task; LastRunTime=05/31/2021 11:14:14; LastTaskResult=0}.TaskName
@{TaskName=FSRM_Update; LastRunTime=05/31/2021 08:00:00; LastTaskResult=0}.TaskName
```

Can someone point me in right direction what am i doing wrong and why is output like this?

//EDIT
Found answer here:
[Testing to see if a scheduled task exist in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703768/testing-to-see-if-a-scheduled-task-exist-in-powershell)

Comment: `Write-Host "$task.TaskName"` -> `Write-Host $task.TaskName`

Comment: Try `$task.TaskName` without the double quotes on both sides.